# Find objects into a list using Django and mongodb

Tags: django, mongodb, django-queryset

I have used django but I'm a newbie with mongodb. I have the follow model:

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    users = ListField(models.CharField(max_length="64"), editable=False)
    messages = ListField(EmbeddedModelField('Message'), editable=False)

class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length="64")
    text = models.CharField(max_length="512");
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

I already store and show conversations with messages for each user, but now I want to filter conversations by some users like a private chat.

For example, I want to get conversations which users contains ['Dennis','linus','Guido']

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

*** EDIT ***

I got it using Q

```
django.db.models.Q
Conversation.objects.filter(Q(users = msg['Dennis'])&Q(users = msg['linus']&Q(users = msg['Guido']))
```

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're using mongoengine?

```
Conversation.objects.filter(users__all=['Dennis','linus','Guido'])
```

Comment: is `__all` a valid queryset filter option ? You probably mean [`__contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains)

Comment: There is an __all option http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html#query-operators

Comment: Ok.. but does the django orm support that was my question.

Comment: Exactly.. thats what i m trying to say.

Comment: :) if so, use mongoengine to retrieve conversations and the django orm (with mysql or anything) for everything else.

Comment: __all gave me an error, __contains gave no data.
using __all at shell I got:
    >>> Conversation.objects.all()[0].users
    [u'Dennis', u'linus', u'Guido']
    >>> Conversation.objects.filter(users__contains=[u'yo'])
    []
Any other suggestion?

Comment: >>> Conversation.objects.filter(users__all = ['yo','tu'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/aras/virtualenv/django13/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 141, in filter
    return self.get_query_set().filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aras/virtualenv/django13/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 552, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aras/virtualenv/django13/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" .....

Comment: you're not using mongoengine yet, you should inherits from mongoengine.Document not django.db.models.Model take a look at the getting started http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#getting-started

Comment: I thought I did. I used this tutorial http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-django-mongodb-engine/

Comment: you're not because the error is in django models, File "/home/aras/virtualenv/django13/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/mode‌​ls/manager.py"